# How to determine if the pointer passed as a function argument is being modified or a copy is being modified?

Tags: go, pointers

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Numbers struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func initial(number *Numbers) {
    number.x = 1
    number.y = 1
}

func final(number *Numbers) {
    number = &Numbers{2, 2}
}

func main() {
    p := Numbers{0, 0}
    fmt.Println(p) //Prints {0 0}

    initial(&p)
    fmt.Println(p) //Prints {1 1}

    final(&p)
    fmt.Println(p) //Expected to print {2, 2} but prints {1, 1}
}
```

Why does the `initial` function modify the pointer, while the `final` function modifies a copy of the pointer?

Both `initial` and `final`'s function parameters point to the memory address of `p` in `main`; `initial` manages to change `p`, while `final` can't.

Any explanation so as why this is the case would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To modify the data pointed to by a pointer, you must dereference the pointer.  The dereference operator is `*`. However, Go will implicitly insert the dereference operation in some cases for ease of use.  For example, `number.x = 1` is translated to `(*number).x = 1`.

This implicit translation may be confusing, but you should see that if it that translation didn't happen, then the expression `number.x = 1` would be meaningless, since `number` is a pointer type and pointers don't have fields.

So in summary, the `initial` function has implicit pointer dereference, while `final` does not.

If you changed `final` to explicitly and correctly dereference, `*number = Numbers{2, 2}`, then it will also change `p`.

Comment: In the case of `number = &Numbers{2, 2}`, as @Burak Serdar mentioned, the pointer is assigned to another `Numbers` instance right?

Comment: Basically, yes. More specifically, the local variable `number` is assigned to the address of a literal `Numbers` value.

Answer (score 1):

The `initial` function works on the passed pointer, which is pointing to the variable allocated in `main`. All changes are performed on the object allocated in `main`.

The `final` function receives the same pointer as an argument, however, it assigns the pointer to another `Numbers` instance. The object in `main` never changes.

There is no copying involved in either function.

Comment: Can you explain why? What does "works on the passed pointer" mean, and how is that different from the second case?